# WCF service doesn't recognise correct JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have the following code:

```
[DataContract]
public class OptimizationServiceSettings
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool StealthMode { get; set; }
}
```

Server:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SetSettings", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
public void SetSettings(OptimizationServiceSettings settings)
{
    if (settings != null)
    {
        _stageOptimizer.ServiceSettings = settings;
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.TraceError("Attemp to set null OptimizationServiceSettings");
    }
}
```

Client:

```
private static void SetSettings()
{
    OptimizationServiceSettings op = new OptimizationServiceSettings();
    op.StealthMode = true;

    string jsonInput = ToJson(op);
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:8080/BlocksOptimizationServices/SetSettings", "POST", jsonInput);
}

private static string ToJson<T>(T data)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, data);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

For some reason the `SetSettings` method on the server always gets a null `settings` object.  If I change the `settings` object type to `string` it all works.  I don't understand what is wrong here.  Everything looks like it is correct.

Here is an example of the `jsonInput` string that I got in `SetSettings` on the client:

```
"{\"StealthMode\":\"true\"}"
```

Comment: What json string you are posting? Can you post value of jsonInput variable here?

Comment: @ PankajKapare added

Comment: Try sending request json something like this { "settings" : {"StealthMode":"true"}}

Comment: @ PankajKapare Is there way to make this with serializer not manully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified the requestbody to be wrapped:

```
[WebInvoke(..., BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ...]
```

Hence, the deserialization only succeeds if you wrap the settings-object within a containing object, as @Pankaj  suggested.

Instead of doing that, you could try to change the attribute to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` to avoid the need to wrap the parameter.